# gulp-sass seems not resolving imports

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have a main.scss file:

```
@import '../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css';
@import '../../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css';



@import 'abstracts/variables';
@import 'abstracts/mixins';
@import 'abstracts/modifiers';
@import 'abstracts/utilities';

@import 'base/general';
@import 'base/menu-box';
@import 'base/content';
@import 'base/animations';

@import 'components/menu-heading';
@import 'components/close-button';
@import 'components/scrollbar';
@import 'components/introduction';
@import 'components/slides';




@import 'sections/about';
@import 'sections/experience';
@import 'sections/contacts';
@import 'sections/education';
```

and these two tasks on my gulp.js file:

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/scss/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass({includePaths:[
          './node_modules/animate.css/animate.css',
          './node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css'
        ]}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/assets/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('concat',  () => {
  return gulp.src('./src/assets/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concat("main.css"))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers:['last 10 versions'],
      cascade:false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass','concat','js','HTMLminify','image-compress','serve'));
```

So, first of all, the sass task compile the main.scss file into css, the path dest is `'./src/assets/src'`, then the concat task has to conact the new main.css file (just created by the sass task) and the ionicons.min.css that is in the same path and send the new file in the dist folder.

Now I'm getting an error by the concat task:

```
Message:
    Failed to find ../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css from C:\Users\giaco\Desktop\Resume Box layout\init\src\assets\css\main.css in [
    .,
    C:\Users\giaco\Desktop\Resume Box layout\init\src\assets\css
]
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

So it seems to me that the sass task are not handling the import (even with the includePaths options). While if I do it this way:

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/scss/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./src/assets/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

things works normally, but then I have to repeat the cssClean; also in the concat task, because leaving it only in the sass task will not get a comprimized css file.

Comment: Is '../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'  correct?  A folder named animate.css with a file inside called animate.css?  If so, I would rename the folder and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

your includePaths should not point to the css directly afaik

```
.pipe(sass({
   includePaths: ['./node_modules', './bower_components'],
}).on('error', sass.logError))
```

and change your scss import to

```
@import 'animate.css/animate';
@import 'perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar';
```

this should import both .css files into your scss

Comment: hi your solution does not works, i think it was only a problem with path recognition, what i have to do is change the path in the main.scss file: @import '../../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'; basically the sass task create a css file and store it in a path, from there to reach the animate.css file i have to put the import part as above

Comment: well ok,thats how i always import my node_modules. but im glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and in my case it was solved by removing the file extension, so in your example:
changing `'../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'` to `'../../node_modules/animate.css/animate'`.